# Selenium using the previous quit drive even after I open a new one. Throwing an error: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a parent web test which is called by the test class like this:

```
public class Webtest
{
protected static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public static WebDriver openUrl(String URL)
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    System.out.println("Driver started :"+ driver);
    return driver;
}

public static WebDriver closeDriver(){
  driver.quit();
  System.out.println("Driver closed :"+ driver);
}
}
```

Now I implement the above in a test class extending it.

```
public class testClass extends WebTest
{

@Test
public void TC01()
{   System.out.println("Test1:" + driver);
    // Do something using driver
}


@Test
public void TC02()
{
 System.out.println("Test2:" + driver);
    // Do something
}
}
```

Now the results:

```
Driver started :FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (dfe4e055-4555-0d4d-8a83-a9a802159ea7)
Test1:FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (dfe4e055-4555-0d4d-8a83-a9a802159ea7)
Driver closed :FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (dfe4e055-4555-0d4d-8a83-a9a802159ea7)
Driver started :FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (1370df47-483b-574c-9792-9bb5fa077364)
Test2:FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (1370df47-483b-574c-9792-9bb5fa077364)
[Error] resulted in an exception: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.
```

Basically, I assume the test2 is using the previous driver. I haven't called the second driver to quit yet but am getting the error. I did put sleep in between every method and tried to but nothing worked. Any help? I am using firefox 46.

Comment: are you calling "closeDriver()" somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined your **openUrl** method as a **@BeforeMethod** it is being called before all other methods, so when your **testClass** calls **TC01**, it opens a new browser first.  Then when you call **TC02**, the **@BeforeMethod** gets invoked again and another, new **WebDriver** is created.  That does not explain the last line error, though.  I'm not sure why it would ever execute the **quit** method since the **closeDriver** method never seems to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question:

You need to address a lot of issues in your code as follows:

1. In `Webtest` class, within `closeDriver()` method, you are quit the driver `driver.quit()` still you trying to get WebDriver in return `public static WebDriver closeDriver()`.
   So change it to `public static void closeDriver()`
2. In `testClass` class, you are trying to extend `WebTest` but your base class is `Webtest`.
   So change it to `public class testClass extends Webtest`
3. To work with Selenium 3.4.0 along with geckodriver v 0.16.1 & latest Mozilla Firefox 53.x you need to download the latest gecko driver and mention the absolute path in your code theough `System.setProperty` before you initialise the driver as follows:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   ```
4. In `Webtest` I can see your are accepting the URL as an argument `public static WebDriver openUrl(String URL)` but I dont see you passing it from `Webtest`. Keep it simple, define the `String URL` within `openUrl()` method as follows:

   ```
   String URL = "http://gmail.com";
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get(URL);
   ```
5. In `closeDriver()` you are quitting the driver by `driver.quit();` next if you `System.out.println("Driver closed :"+ driver);` you won't get any realtime value of the driver instance but only `null`.
6. Finally, the entire chaos is created because you have added `@BeforeMethod` annotation to open the driver but haven't released it `closeDriver()` method using `@AfterMethod` annotation. Add the annotation `@AfterMethod`.
7. Here is your own working code along with some simple tweaks:

class Webtest :

```
    public class Webtest 
    {

    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public static WebDriver openUrl()
    {
        String URL = "http://gmail.com";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        System.out.println("Within openUrl() - Driver started :"+ driver);
        return driver;
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public static void closeDriver()
    {
      driver.quit();
      System.out.println("Driver closed :"+ driver);

    }
    }
```

class testClass :

```
    public class testClass extends Webtest
    {

    @Test
    public void TC01()
    {   
        System.out.println("Within TC01 - Test1:" + driver);
        // Do something using driver
    }


    @Test
    public void TC02()
    {
        System.out.println("Within TC02 - Test2:" + driver);
        // Do something
    }
    }
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.